how to query a different view depending on oracle version
i have 2 queries.The 1st one runs on 11g:
select  owner,directory_name,directory_path from dba_directories;
The 2nd one runs on 12c an 19c oracle versions only:
select  owner,directory_name,directory_path from cdb_directories;
The objective is to combine these 2 sql's into a single query such that it runs seemlessly without any error on any version of the database.
Please note the combined query will be run in OEM as a metric.
i have tried a few variants, but didnt work.
with version_check as ( select case  when substr(version,1,2)= '11' then '11' else 'OTHER' end as db_version from v$instance ) select d.db_unique_name||':'||dd.owner||':'||dd.directory_name DB_OWNER_DIRECTORY,dd.owner, dd.directory_name, dd.DIRECTORY_PATH from dba_directories dd, v$database d where (select db_version from version_check)= '11' union all select d.db_unique_name||':'||cd.owner||':'||cd.directory_name DB_OWNER_DIRECTORY, cd.owner,cd.directory_name,cd.directory_path FROM cdb_directories cd, v$database d WHERE cd.origin_con_id NOT IN (0, 1)  AND (REGEXP_LIKE (cd.directory_path,sys_context('USERENV', 'ORACLE_HOME')) OR REGEXP_LIKE (cd.directory_path,'/tmp') OR REGEXP_LIKE (cd.directory_path,'/usr/tmp')) and (select db_version from version_check)<> '11';
The above gives ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Use the below DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML trick to create a pure SQL statement that will run different SQL depending on the version of the database. This result is pretty similar to previous questions you've asked, so you might want to save this code as a template for any future question involving a single SQL statement that runs on multiple versions.
--Directory information from either DBA or CDB tables, depending on the database version.
--
--#4: Get the size from the XMLType.
select db_owner_directory, owner, directory_name, directory_path
from
(
    --#3: Convert the XML to an XMLType.
    select xmltype(xml_clob_results) xmltype_results
    from
    (
        --#2: Convert the SQL to XML.
        select dbms_xmlgen.getxml(v_sql) xml_clob_results
        from
        (
            --#1: Use data dictionary to create SQL statement based on which views exist.
            select
                case when substr(version,1,2)= '11' then
                    q'[
                        select d.db_unique_name||':'||dd.owner||':'||dd.directory_name DB_OWNER_DIRECTORY,dd.owner, dd.directory_name, dd.DIRECTORY_PATH
                        from dba_directories dd, v$database d
                    ]'
                else
                    q'[
                        select d.db_unique_name||':'||cd.owner||':'||cd.directory_name DB_OWNER_DIRECTORY, cd.owner,cd.directory_name,cd.directory_path
                        FROM cdb_directories cd, v$database d
                        WHERE cd.origin_con_id NOT IN (0, 1) 
                            -- Commented out these predicates because they threw an error on my system.
                            --AND (REGEXP_LIKE (cd.directory_path,sys_context('USERENV', 'ORACLE_HOME'))
                            --OR REGEXP_LIKE (cd.directory_path,'/tmp')
                            --OR REGEXP_LIKE (cd.directory_path,'/usr/tmp')
                            --)
                    ]'
                end v_sql
            from v$instance
        )
    )
    where xml_clob_results is not null
)
cross join xmltable
(
    '/ROWSET/ROW'
    passing xmltype_results
    columns
        DB_OWNER_DIRECTORY varchar2(4000) path 'DB_OWNER_DIRECTORY',
        OWNER varchar2(4000) path 'OWNER',
        DIRECTORY_NAME varchar2(4000) path 'DIRECTORY_NAME',
        DIRECTORY_PATH varchar2(4000) path 'DIRECTORY_PATH'
);


You won't be able to do that - an object name in a SQL statement must be resolvable at parse time, and there are no cdb* views in 11g, so your SQL will always fail parse.
You will have to use version-specific SQL that is determined at run-time by something other than SQL. That can be PL/SQL using dynamic SQL (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) to prevent parsing inappropriate SQLs, or any programming language outside the database.
I suggest the latter; over the years I've written and managed an extensive monitoring system that covers every version from 8i to 19c and pulls everything imaginable. I keep versioned script pieces (e.g. here's a 8i version, here's one for 10.2.0.1 to 10.2.0.4, etc..) for each versionable SQL statement or PL/SQL block and then piece together the appropriate versions of each script piece at run time to create a fully versioned script that can run against that particular version. This works quite well for monitoring a varied footprint. The point is, make the versioning decision and code-construction take place outside the database if possible.
If you are building an OEM custom metric, then define a different one for each version and add the appropriate one to the applicable databases.
